# Avoiding deletion of first row when deleting selected row

Tags: java, database, swing, delete-row

Before I added the `Yes/No` options, the `delete` button deleted only the desired row. However, after adding the `Yes/No` Option, the first row in the database gets deleted along with the desired row.

```
        b6.addActionListener (new ActionListener ()
        {
            JFrame f4=new JFrame("Are you sure?");
            JPanel p4=new JPanel();
            JButton yes=new JButton ("Yes");
            JButton no=new JButton ("No");
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
            {
                p4.add (yes);
                p4.add (no);
                f4.add (p4);
                f4.setVisible (true);
                f4.setSize (300,200);

                yes.addActionListener (new ActionListener ()
                    {
                        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                f4.dispose();
                                rs.deleteRow();
                                rs.close();//
                                st.close();//to prevent gap in database
                         st=conn.createStatement(rs.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,rs.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
                                String sql="select * from trial1";
                                rs= st.executeQuery (sql);
                                rs.next();
                                t.setText (rs.getString ("Firstname"));
                                t1.setText (rs.getString ("Lastname"));
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                            }
                        }
                    });

                no.addActionListener (new ActionListener ()
                    {
                        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
                        {
                            f4.dispose();
                        }
                    });

            }
        });
```

Comment: Consider adding a language tag to your post. Thanks

Comment: I did. I didn't know how to do that before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the glitch by making a small alteration to the position of the f4.dispose(), and also by including a try and catch block in the ActionListener for b6.

```
 b6.addActionListener (new ActionListener ()
        {
            JFrame f4=new JFrame("Are you sure?");
            JPanel p4=new JPanel();
            JButton yes=new JButton ("Yes");
            JButton no=new JButton ("No");
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
            {
                p4.add (yes);
                p4.add (no);
                f4.add (p4);
                f4.setVisible (true);
                f4.setSize (300,200);
                try {
                    yes.addActionListener (new ActionListener ()
                        {
                            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    rs.deleteRow();
                                    rs.close();
                                    st.close();
                                    st=conn.createStatement(rs.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, rs. CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
                                    String sql="select * from trial1";
                                    rs= st.executeQuery (sql);
                                    rs.next();
                                    t.setText (rs.getString ("Firstname"));
                                    t1.setText (rs.getString ("Lastname"));
                                    f4.dispose();
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    no.addActionListener (new ActionListener ()
                        {
                            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
                            {
                                f4.dispose();
                            }
                        });

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Tentative answer, as I have no way of checking this right now:

I think the fact that you are adding the `ActionListener` to `yes` from **within** the `b6`'s `actionPerformed()` when it is called means that the second time you click it (`b6`), you actually have **two** action listeners on the same `yes` button.

Therefore when you press the `yes` button, the action is performed twice. So the first time, the `rs` cursor is set to the row you selected. But in that action, you set `rs` to a new query (`select * from trial1`) in order to fill up the fields.

So when the second action listener is activated, that's where `rs` is pointing - to the first record of this last query. And that's the record that will get deleted.

To avoid all this, you have to add the `ActionListener` to `yes` outside of `actionPerformed()` - perhaps in an initializer block?

Comment: I put the f4.dispose() after the t1.setText (rs.getString ("Lastname"));. I also added a try and catch block to the b6 ActionListener, and the problem was solved. Thanks anyways.